# Test Angular Component with setTimeout in method

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, jasmine, tdd

I'm trying to test a method in an angular component like so:

```
  answerSelect(answer: any): void {
    this.selectedAnswer = answer;

    // submit the answer
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (answer.correct) this.submit();
      this.selectedAnswer = undefined;
    }, 500);
  }
```

This is what I have so far:

```
 describe('answerSelect()', () => {

      it('should set this.selectedAnswer = answer', async(() => {
        spyOn(instance, 'answerSelect').and.callThrough();
        instance.selectedAnswer = 'notTheAnswer';
        instance.answerSelect(('answer'));

        expect(instance.selectedAnswer).toBe('answer');
      }));

      it('should submit the answer', async(() => {
        spyOn(instance, 'answerSelect').and.callThrough();
        spyOn(instance, 'submit');
        instance.selectedAnswer = 'notTheAnswer';
        instance.answerSelect({correct: true});

        expect(instance.submit).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(instance.selectedAnswer).toBe(undefined);
      }));

  });
```

The first test (`should set this.selectedAnswer = answer`) works as expected.

However, I cannot seem to get the second test (`should submit the answer`) working due to the `setTimeout()` and am getting the following two errors:

1) `Expected spy submit to have been called.` so `this.submit()` doesn't get called.

and

2) `Expected Object({ correct: true }) to be undefined.` so `this.selectedAnswer = undefined;` doesn't get called either.

How can I ensure that both of these functions within the `setTimeout` get called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I ensure that both of these functions within the setTimeout get called?

Add a delay in your test and make sure your test is also async.

## More

Checkout jasmine async support https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support

Answer (score 0):

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms)
    })
}
```

and add `await sleep(2000)` after `instance.answerSelect({correct: true});`

Answer (score -1):

1. Inject [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$timeout) service into your tests.
2. Control the time in your tests with timeout.flush() function.

For an example of such a test case, see [this spec](https://github.com/Pragmatists/whack-a-mole-angularjs/blob/postdata/src/app/mole/mole.directiveController.spec.js).